# I need to show "I can set up the framework of assumptions and conclusions for a proof by contradiction and correctly carry out such a proof."

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following proof so far but need to justify all claims. Am I missing anything? How can I improve?

Question: Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ is a bounded sequence such that every convergent subsequence converges to the same limit $a_\infty$. Show the whole sequence also converges to $a_\infty$.

Proof: Suppose for contradiction that $\{a_n\}$ diverges. Since $\{a_n\}$ does not converge to $a_\infty$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $N\in\mathbf{N}$, there exists $n_N>N$ such that $\vert{a_{n_N}}-a_\infty\vert\geq\epsilon$. Hence we have a subsequence $(a_{n_1}, a_{n_2},...)$ such that $\vert{a_{n_k}}-a_\infty\vert\geq\epsilon$ for all $k\in\mathbf{N}$. Since $\{a_n\}$ is bounded, the subsequence is also bounded, and by the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem it has a subsequence $\{a_{j_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ which converges to some number $b$. But $a_\infty  \neq b$ since $\vert{a_{j_k}}-a_\infty\vert\geq\epsilon$. So $\{a_n\}$ contains two convergent subsequences $\{a_{i_k}\}$ and $\{a_{j_k}\}$ that converge to two different limits. This is a contradiction. So, $\{a_n\}\rightarrow a_\infty$.

Comment: If it were me, I would shorten the last part: By Bolzano Weierstrass we have a convergent subsequence $\{a_{j_k}\}$, but by construction, for all $k$, $|a_{j_k}-a_{\infty}|\geq \epsilon$. So, $a_{j_k}$ does not converge to $a_{\infty}$, hence contradicting the hypothesis. (this way you don't have to unnecessarily introduce $b$ and $\{a_{i_k}\}$). But anyway, it's fine as it is

Comment: For completeness you may want to mention that $\,\{a_n\}\,$ is a bounded **real** sequence, or equivalent wording. See the Wikipedia article [Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem). The theorem is not true for all sequences in general topological spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two comments.

1. To say that $(a_{n_1}, a_{n_2},\cdots)$ is a subsequence of the original sequence, you need $n_1<n_2<n_3<\cdots$. This can be arranged for by replacing each $n_N$ with $n_N'=\max\{n_k \mid 1\leq k \leq N\}$.
2. You don't need to say in the end that you have two subsequences with different limits. You have already shown that $a_{j_k} \to b$ as $k \to \infty$ and $b \neq a_{\infty}$, and this alone is a contradiction.

Other than that everything seems very good.